# Count with <key,value>

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have created these two functions:

```
var mapFunction = function () {
if (this.type == "Book")
emit(this.title, this);
};
var reduceFunction = function (key, values) {
return {articles : values};
};
```

For each key <publisher,year>, I want to retrieve the number of publications.

How can I achieve this ?

This is my current input :

```
 {"_id": "phd/Klink2006","type": "Phd", "title": "IQForCE - Intelligent Query (Re-)Formulation with Concept-based Expansion", "year": 2006, "publisher": "Verlag Dr. Hut, M?nchen", "authors": ["Stefan Klink"], "isbn": ["3-89963-303-2"]},
```

Expected output :

```
Publisher               Year Number of publications
Verlag Dr. Hut, M?nchen 2006 //count of publications in 2006
```

Comment: Please add sample data, expected output.

Comment: Thank you, can you please add sample data on which you're running your query.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar I shared the input. instead of writing input I wrote output I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/7aDMu5QhDvk

Use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { year: "$year", publisher: "$publisher" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

---

You can reshape the data using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/KfZd0CVigw3

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0, year: "$_id.year", publisher: "$_id.publisher", count: "$count"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you make a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149244/select-distinct-authors-for-a-book