# SELECT distinct authors for a book

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following input :

```
{"_id": "series/cogtech/BertonKHS06","type": "Article", "title": "Speech Recognition.", "pages": {"start": 85, "end": 107}, "year": 2006, "booktitle": "SmartKom", "url": "db/series/cogtech/54023732.html#BertonKHS06", "authors": ["Andr? Berton","Alfred Kaltenmeier","Udo Haiber","Olaf Schreiner"]}
```

I want to get all the authors separetly with their books, I tried this query :

```
db.publis.find({}, {authors:1, title:2, _id:0})
```

My expected output :

```
Book                Author
Speech Recognition  Andr? Berton
Speech Recognition  Alfred Kaltenmeier
Speech Recognition  Udo Haiber
Speech Recognition  Olaf Schreiner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/86ZQkXfN4BW

Use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$authors" }, // break into individual documents
  { $project: { _id: 0, book: "$title", author: "$authors" } }
])
```

Comment: Can you make a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149495/select-count-with-having-clause