# SELECT COUNT with HAVING clause

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my input :

```
 {"_id": "phd/Klink2006","type": "Phd", "title": "IQForCE - Intelligent Query (Re-)Formulation with Concept-based Expansion", "year": 2006, "publisher": "Verlag Dr. Hut, M?nchen", "authors": ["Stefan Klink"], "isbn": ["3-89963-303-2"]}
```

I want to count books that have less than 3 authors. How can I reach this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by null, check condition if size of authors is less than 3 then count 1 otherwise 0

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $lt: [{ $size: "$authors" }, 3] },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YlKKn5p4Mtf)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator (this will return all the documents).

```
db.collection.find({
  "$where": "this.authors.length < 3"
});
```

Important consideration:

> $where evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes.
> Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query
> using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., $gt, $in).

> In general, you
> should use $where only when you cannot express your query using
> another operator. If you must use $where, try to include at least one
> other standard query operator to filter the result set. Using $where
> alone requires a collection scan.

The best options in term of performance is to create a new key `authorsLength`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "authorsLength": {
        "$lt": 3
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Starting in MongoDB 4.4, $where no longer supports the deprecated BSON type JavaScript code with scope (BSON type 15). The $where operator only supports BSON type String (BSON type 2) or BSON type JavaScript (BSON type 13). The use of BSON type JavaScript with scope for $where has been deprecated since MongoDB 4.2.1.